# RxSwift Variable (Behavior Subject) does not emit signals

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I have a simple ViewModel:

```
struct ViewModel {
    var someText = Variable<String>("")

    func foo() -> Observable<String> {
        return someText.asObservable()
    }
}
```

In the ViewController, viewModel is the instance variable, and someTextField is a UITextField with IBOutlet connected properly

```
var viewModel = ViewModel()
@IBOutlet weak var someTextField: UITextField!
```

Then in viewDidLoad() of the ViewController, I set things up and do the following:

```
someTextField.rx.text.map { $0 ?? "" }.bind(to: viewModel.someText)

let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
let observable = viewMode.foo()
observable.subscribe(onNext: { data in
            print(data)
        }, onError: { error in
            print(error)
        }, onCompleted: {
            print ("complete")
        }, onDisposed: {
            print("disposed")
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

As I enter characters in the textfield, I expect print() to print out these characters. But print() is only invoked once in the debugger (and not subsequently when text field receives input)

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have to retain your `disposeBag` outside the context and the `someTextField.rx.text.map { $0 ?? "" }.bind(to: viewModel.someText)` should be `disposed(by: disposeBag)`.

Comment: Your answer, though not 100% correct, leads me to find the right answer.

Comment: Can you tell us what was wrong about his answer? And what was your solution?

Comment: @KevinLe-Khnle Can you post your findings?